# forced reformat without login / and bootcamp

Tags: formatting, boot-camp

ok.. im pretty good with stuff like this, but I have a question.

I have mac mini with 10.5.(x) on one partition, and bootcamp (windows) on the other. My boss wants me to reformat the whole mac (10.6 (x)), which is usually easy.  He does not remember his password to login, which means I cannot log in and allocate the bootcamp back to one partition using Disk Utility, then reformat the whole drive.

When I insert the Snow leopard CD, I can only wipe out one partition, my question is: Is there a way to force a wipe out of both drives in the boot sequence?

Any help to wipe out this whole drive and do a clean install would be helpful.. Thanks superusers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter the Snow Leopard DVD, then select "Disk Utility" from the "Utilities" menu at the top. From there, you can repartition or format the disk.

**Edit**

I probably should have mentioned the "Reset Password" Utility in the same menu :P

Answer (score 2):

[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) would work. You can create a [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), boot into the Mac Mini, and delete all the partitions on the drive. Don't worry about creating a new partition with GParted. Let the Snow Leopard install take care of that for you.

[image]